# Highlight RibbonButton after clicking

Tags: c#, wpf, highlight, ribbon

is there any chance to highlight RibbonButton after clicking and remove it after clicking again? Im using xaml and code behind event after clicking button.

Comment: Great. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you already have some code but it just isn't working properly? Take a look at the [RibbonButton docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) for some guidance. Also could you be a little more explicit in what you mean by _"highlight RibbonButton after clicking and remove it after clicking again"_ Does it have to instantly be clicked again or just a second time ever?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a RibbonToggleButton instead, it should have the behavior you're looking for. If you want to keep track of the state of the button you can set a binding on the isChecked property which will be true when the button is highlighted.